# Google Sheet: How do I pass in ARRAYFORMULA into QUERY?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I want to pass in ARRAYFORMULA into the QUERY so that I can get the sum without splitting the two functions apart.

I want to do this but getting an error ("unable to parse query string for function query parameter"):

```
=QUERY(ARRAYFORMULA(SPLIT(O5:O7, " to ")),"select sum(O),sum(P)")
```

**Example:**

This is the input:

```
1.080 to 3.240
0.771 to 2.312
0.721 to 2.164
```

Above input is pass in as **O5:O7**. Using this function, it will split into 2 columns and extract the number:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SPLIT(O5:O7, " to ")
```

As result, shown as following:

```
1.08    3.24
0.771   2.312
0.721   2.164
```

The above result will be pass into as **O18:P20**. This function will give the sum of each columns:

```
=QUERY(O18:P20,"select sum(O),sum(P)")
```

Result as the following:

```
sum     sum 
2.572   7.716
```

Could I pass in the arrayformula's result into the query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `BYCOL()` lambda function after splitting. Try-

```
=BYCOL(INDEX(SPLIT(P5:P7," to ")),LAMBDA(x,SUM(x)))
```

Or `QUERY()` function like-

```
=QUERY(INDEX(SPLIT(P5:P7," to ")),"select sum(Col1),sum(Col2)")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

yes:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(SPLIT(O5:O7, " to "), "select sum(Col1),sum(Col2)"))
```

if you dont need labels:

```
=INDEX(QUERY(SPLIT(O5:O7, " to "), "select sum(Col1),sum(Col2)"), 2)
```